# iOS 11 prefersLargeTitles not displaying until scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I'm having issues with iOS 11's large titles when using a Table View Controller.

I have set `prefersLargeTitles` to true in the viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

When running my app the title appears as if `prefersLargeTitles` is set to small, but if I then scroll down, the large title appears.

I have 2 `UIViewControllers`, and they both display the large title correctly, bar the `UITableViewController`.

I have tried different combinations of setting `prefersLargeTitles` to true in the code and within the storyboard, where you can set `Large Title` to `Automatic`, `Always` or `Never`.

I can only find one other question on Stack Overflow which refers to this exact issue, but none of the answers seem to solve it.

Has anyone else who has run into this issue been able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable large titles on the navigation controller. It is tricky to find, so please see the screenshot below.
[image]

If your table view controller seques on to other detail view controllers then you should set `large title` to `Never` in the storyboard for those other view controllers.

DO NOT MESS with `prefersLargeTitles` in code like this:

```
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Answer (score 5):

After setting `prefersLargeTitles`, you can trigger the large titles to show by calling setContentOffset on your UITableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are reloading the `tableView` prior to `viewDidLoad`? I observed the same behavior today. In my case, I had a `didSet` on a variable that was set before `viewDidLoad` that called `tableView.reloadData`.

I was able to fix this by adding a guard so the `reloadData` only happened when the variable wasn't previously `nil`, meaning the first time.

Here's my calling class for reference...

```
/// Master Controller in UISplitViewController
class MyMasterViewController: UIViewController {

  private let controller = MyTableViewController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    controller.instanceVariable = data
    showDetailViewController(navigationController, sender: self)
  }

...

  private func reloadDetail() {
    controller.instanceVariable = newData
  }
}
```

And here's the fix - added the `guard` statement below...

```
/// Detail Controller in UISplitViewController
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var instanceVariable: MyData! {
    didSet {
      guard oldValue != nil else { return }
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  // UITableViewController Methods...
}
```

Hope this helps! If my example doesn't make sense, I'd suggest commenting out all references to `tableView.reloadData` and then only re-adding when sure they aren't getting called until after the `tableView` loads initially.

Comment: This solved a problem I've been having for months. In my case, I was setting the table view data source in a didSet block, which generated the exact behaviour you described.